# Not able to add .net assemblies in Test Partner Tool

Tags: .net-framework-version, microfocus

We have automated an application using Test Partner 6. We have a grid in the application which has the class name "GUIObject("ClassName=WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.15a303f_r38_ad1 Caption='' Index=18")". We create a object of this and get the column titles.

Now we have an upgrade of the application. We are able to create the object but its an empty object. When we try to do any operation on it it throws error "invalid procedure call or arguement'. We tried adding the .Net reference and assemblies. But getting the error "This is an invalid .net assembly"
This works well with older version of application, but not new. Dot Net framework 4.5 is installed in our machine.

Any help appreciated.